# How to call function of another component in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, react-redux, rxjs

I am new to react and I want to call play() function of audioplayer.js from music.js. I heard about context api, but i am not sure how to use it. When i click the button it should call play() function from another component

```js
//music.js
...
<div class = "music-content-container">
                    <div class = "music-box">
                        <div class = "user-musics">
                            <ul>
                                {musics && musics.map((name, index)=>{
                                    return(
                                        <>
                                            <li key = {index}><button onClick = {play()} value = {name}>Play</button>{name}</li>//the button should go to the play function of audioplayer.js
                                        </>
                                    )
                                })}
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                
            </div>
            <AudioPlayer title = {audioTitle}/>
...
```

this what audioplayer.js looks like....

```js
function AudioPlayer(props){
    //ignore this part
    const audioRef = useRef();
    const audioPlayer = audioRef.current
    const [audioSrc, setAudioSrc] = useState()

    useEffect(()=>{
        if(props.title){
            firebase.database().ref("public/songs/"+props.title).on("value", (snapshot)=>{
                setAudioSrc(snapshot.val().aduioURL)
            })
    }
    }, [props.play])

    const [progVal, setProgVal] = useState("0%")
    function update(event){
        let duration = (event.target.currentTime/event.target.duration)*100
        setProgVal(duration)
    }

    // i want it to call this function when it plays
    function play(e){
        audioPlayer.play()
    }

    function stop(){
        audioPlayer.pause();
    }
    return(
            <div className = "audio-wrapper">
                <div className = "audio-container">
                    <div className = "audio-box">
                        <audio id = "player" ref = {audioRef} src = {audioSrc} name = "audioplayer" onTimeUpdate = {update}>
                        </audio>
                        <button onClick = {play}>Play</button>
                        <button onClick = {stop}>stop</button>
                        <div class = "progress_div">
                            <div class = "progress_holder" id= "prog_holder">
                                <div id = "progress_meter" style = {{width: progVal + "%"}}></div>
                            </div>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
    )
}

export default AudioPlayer
```

Any answer would help me alot, and tell me if there is any method of doing this.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, React likes to work 'top down' i.e. by passing props from parent to children.  Its a bad practice to architect your components in a way that you rely on the parent being able to *call* a function in a child.  You also don't need `context` for this, as its not a deeply nested tree of components.

One possible solution is to have the AudioPlayer auto play the song when it receives a valid value for the `title` prop.  Use some state in the `music` component to maintain which is the currently loaded song.  Set this state property when clicking on your play button in the list of songs.

Comment: posted from a phone, so apologies cannot give specific code examples

Comment: Thank you for the answer, i think i will change the structure of the whole code, I will probably make that function in parent and use props to call the function. thank you

Answer (score 0):

One quick work around would be to create a state in the music js like this

```
const [audioPlayer,setAudioPlayer] = useState(null);
```

Now pass this setAudioPlayer as prop to the AudioPlayer

```
 <AudioPlayer setAudioPlayer={setAudioPlayer} title = {audioTitle}/>
```

Now in the useEffect call

```
setAudioPlayer(audioRef.current)
```

So now in the state audioPlayer of the music.js you have access to methods of the AudioPlayer.js

This is a work around not so sure about whether this is the right way.